# Using Vagrant and VM with python-django & PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, virtual-machine, vagrant

I am trying to make a python-django project on a VM with Python/Django 2.7.6 and PostgreSQL 9.3.4 installed.

I am following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial. After making [changes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES) in settings.py for Postgres, when I do vagrant up and vagrant ssh, and after python manage.py syncdb, it shows the following error.

```
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
translation.activate('en-us')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
return _trans.activate(language)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
_active.value = translation(language)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
app = import_module(appname)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
class Permission(models.Model):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 25, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
```

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2

Also one more thing, I am able to run a project with SQLite on the VM.

What to do ?

Answer (score 3):

`pyscopg2` is the name of the Python module normally used to interface with Postgresql. You will need to install it.

You should be able to install it using Pip with `pip install psycopg2`. Pip itself can usually be found using your package manager - on Ubuntu, for instance, IIRC the package is called python-pip for Python 2 and python3-pip for Python 3.